# Passing Parameters to Index List Controller in MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with this codes, it always gives me empty result:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? sipno)
    {
        var kolaycam_acsgoContext = _context.siparis_detay
            .Where(s => s.Siparis_no == sipno);
        return View(await kolaycam_acsgoContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

But if I dont use parameter like this it works. What am I do wrong?

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var kolaycam_acsgoContext = _context.siparis_detay
            .Where(s => s.Siparis_no == 901120);
        return View(await kolaycam_acsgoContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Comment: How do you call the Index method from your View?

Comment: What's the value of `sipno`? Did you debug it?

Comment: I use "sipno" with same value on my second code.

"https://localhost:44364/siparis_detay/index/901120" is my url by the way.

Comment: Unless you have `sipno` set up as a route value, you'd need to use `"localhost:44364/siparis_detay/index?sipno=901120"` for what you've shown to work.

Comment: Thank you Kirk Larkin! How can I setup a route value for this page?

my default route is this:

`                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`

Comment: You can either use `int? id` and `s.Siparis_no == id` or `[FromRoute(Name="id")] int? sipno`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that silly mistake, when I change sipno to id it worked.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
    var kolaycam_acsgoContext = _context.siparis_detay
        .Where(s => s.Siparis_no == id);
    return View(await kolaycam_acsgoContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Merhaba Tuğhan hocam nasılsın ? (: "

I Think Problem is variable type **int?** **sipno** variable may be coming empty
Another problem is that **s => s.Siparis_no** property type

is it a **int?**  ? If it is not important to have the same type for comparison

did you debug ? if you did, what is value of **sipno**

please review this answers and please report your result

Comment: "Merhaba Baran teşekkür ederim sen?:)"

I'm using "https://localhost:44364/siparis_detay/index/901120" it has to give me same result but it doesn't. Type is int, I don't know why we use ? but I use it because of other samples. On my second code everything works well.

Comment: "Teşekkürler (:" **int** and **int?** different types. If **sipno** type is a **int?** then **s.Siparis_no** same type has to be. Please tell me debug results and **sipno** variable value ?